# Getting live updates in WebApi REST service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET WebApi Self-hosted service, which does some work with an object called `Transaction`. Also, I have a separate WinForms application, which serves me as a client to which I download `Transaction`. It is possible, that client could be Web application on Android application (service shouldn't care about it).

`Transaction` has a property named `Status`, which changes from submitted -> inprogress -> done/error during the operation.

Currently, my client works like this:

```
SubmitTransaction(Transaction t);

while(t.Status==inprogress)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   t= GetTransactionStatus();
}
```

As you see, I have to "PING" my service every second to get an status update. I'm wondering, is there any way to "listen" to my service and return `Status`, when it get's updated on service without loop and sleep? I'm using .NET 3.5

Please, feel free to ask more information,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [push notification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

There are many library and implementation. The most famous in .net is [SignalIR](http://signalr.net/)

There you can find an exemple on how to use it in not-webcontext: http://mscodingblog.blogspot.it/2012/12/testing-signalr-in-wpf-console-and.html

Anyway they are quite complex to setup and if you think you will have only a few client to request about that transaction and you don't need realtime pushnotification for other aspect of your app I think it is easier/faster to just check for status any X seconds as you are doing.

PS Please use a [Timer and not Thread.Sleep](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx)

Comment: It wasn't too hard to implement SignalR notifications to my existing service :) The only trouble was to migrate my existing client from .NET 3.5 -> .NET 4.0 as this is minimum requirement to SignalR client.